# Live search with php ajax Multiple Values

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I wnat to pass  `subject` value to the page `fetch.php` using AJAX. So that, i can get **Subject** name in `fetch.php` using `$subj=$_POST['subject'];`

Codes tha i am using are

```
<div class="card-header">Search Question</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subj" class="form-control"  value="Physics" />
            <input type="text" name="search_box" id="search_box" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your search query here" />
          </div>
          <div class="table-responsive" id="dynamic_content">
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    load_data(1);

    function load_data(page, query = '')
    {
      $.ajax({
        url:"fetch.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{page:page, query:query},
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#dynamic_content').html(data);
        }
      });
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.page-link', function(){
      var page = $(this).data('page_number');
      var query = $('#search_box').val();
      load_data(page, query);
    });

    $('#search_box').keyup(function(){
      var query = $('#search_box').val();
      load_data(1, query);
    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at how the `query` is being handled, you can probably infer how to pass other values (like `subject`) in a similar manner.

I would start by refactoring the code a bit, especially the event handlers:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".page-link", function () {
  loadDataByPageNumber($(this).data("page_number"));
});

$("#search_box").keyup(function () {
  loadDataByPageNumber(1);
});

function loadDataByPageNumber(page) {
  var query = $("#search_box").val();
  var subject = $("#subj").val();
  load_data(page, subject, query);
}
```

Then the `load_data` function can be modified to accept the `subject` parameter as well:

```js
function load_data(page, subject, query = "") {
  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: { page: page, query: query, subject: subject },
    success: function (data) {
      $("#dynamic_content").html(data);
    },
  });
}
```